# Showing dialog after checking connection to main server

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a splashscreen that called with `Starter`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    StartAnimations();

    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(isPingAvailable("https://myurl.co.id")) {
                Intent startActivity = new Intent(Starter.this, Login_activity.class);
                startActivity(startActivity);
            }else{
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        AskOption();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

here is how i show my dialog , still in same file

```
private AlertDialog AskOption()
{
    AlertDialog myQuittingDialogBox =new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Cannot connect to Main server")
            .setMessage("Refresh app ? ")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    restartActivity(Starter.this);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .create();
    return myQuittingDialogBox;

}
```

and here is my `isPingAvailable()`

```
 public static boolean isPingAvailable(String myUrl) {
        boolean isAvailable = false;

        try {
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return null;
                        }
                        public void checkClientTrusted(
                                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        }
                        public void checkServerTrusted(
                                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        }
                    }
            };

            try {
                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Tag","Err " + e);
            }

            URL url = new URL(myUrl);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // 30 second time out.
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                isAvailable = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            isAvailable = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return isAvailable;
    }
```

So when i try with my real `url` my app is open `Login_activity` but when i want open random url like `https://myurl.co.id`, my app stuck in splashscreen instead of showing `AskOption()`. How can i fix it ?

Comment: What is `isPingAvailable()` ? Post it .

Comment: Can you post your code of isPingAvailable()..

Comment: @ADM I have post it

Comment: @YVS1102  Please post exception while you pick random url.

Comment: Thats a `HttpURLConnection` hit should be on background thread , and you can not call it inside `if` directly . You have to wait for response . Use a callback for ping failure an success .

Comment: @ChetanPatel `java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "https://myurl.co.id": No address associated with hostname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call show method for dialog.try this

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                      AskOption().show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            (new BackWork()).execute("your url");
        }
    }, 1000);



(new BackWork()).execute("your url");

class BackWork extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        return isPingAvailable(strings[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        if(aBoolean) {
            Intent startActivity = new Intent(Starter.this, Login_activity.class);
            startActivity(startActivity);
        }else{
            uiThread();
        }
    }
}

private void uiThread(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AskOption().show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you creating object on `AlertDialog` but you are not calling `show method`. Now you can write your code into `AskOption()` where you need to call `show()` on your `AlertDialog`. Do below on your `AskOption()` :-

```
myQuittingDialogBox.show()
```